# Brownian motion with drift as interval goes to zero

Tags: continuity, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm struggling to understand how the continuity of a standard Brownian motion is affected by the addition of the drift. Let me explain my  doubts by means of  the following question.

Consider a Brownian motion with constant drift $\mu$ and scale parameter $\sigma$:
$$X_t = \mu t + \sigma Z_t$$
where $Z_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Let $r \in R$ be a scalar and consider the indicator function $1_{[r, \infty)}(X_t)$ that takes value one if $X_t \in [r, \infty)$ and zero otherwise.

1. What is the expectation $E\{1_{[r, \infty)}(X_{t+\Delta})|X_t\}$ of the indicator function at $X_{t+\Delta}$ conditional on $X_t$, for $\Delta > 0$?
2. What happens in the limit for $\Delta  \rightarrow 0$?

My basic intuition would be that in the limit  the expectation becomes degenerate, taking values one and zero depending  on whether $X_t \in [r,  \infty)$ or not, but it might well be that the drift changes things. Is the intuition correct?

Comment: Intuition sounds right, the drift would affect what happens for non-zero $\Delta$: the larger the drift, the more the probability to hit the interval even though $X_t$ is far away from it, or in reverse, the more the probability to escape the interval even though $X_t$ is deep into it.